# "bourbon install" doesn't do anything

Tags: terminal, sass, bourbon

I have run

```
Matthews-iMac:~ mattbtay2$ sudo gem install bourbon
Password:
Fetching: bourbon-4.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bourbon-4.0.2
Parsing documentation for bourbon-4.0.2
Installing ri documentation for bourbon-4.0.2
1 gem installed
```

But when in try to add bourbon into the project:

```
Matthews-iMac:bourb mattbtay2$ bourbon install
Matthews-iMac:bourb mattbtay2$
```

not sure why nothing is happening. I can install Neat, and Bitters just fine. When I run

```
bourbon -h
```

I get

```
Matthews-iMac:bourb mattbtay2$ bourbon -h

Usage: bourbon [options] [command]

Commands:

new <path>            
run [options] [path]  

Options:

-h, --help     output usage information
-V, --version  output the version number
```

I don't even see an install command. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Version 4.0.2 should give you this response:

```
[~/Code/bourbon-test] gem install bourbon
Successfully installed bourbon-4.0.2
1 gem installed
[~/Code/bourbon-test] bourbon -h
Commands:
  bourbon help [COMMAND]  # Describe available commands or one specific command
  bourbon install         # Install Bourbon into your project
  bourbon update          # Update Bourbon
  bourbon version         # Show Bourbon version
```

It doesn't look like bourbon has used "new" and "run" in a long time. Maybe it isn't updating the executables for some reason. Try `gem uninstall bourbon` and `gem install bourbon` again.

Comment: So after i uninstall and reinstall bourbon i see this 
 
`Matthews-iMac:~ mattbtay2$ bourbon --version
0.0.0  `

Comment: same issue for me. did you ever figure this out?